# How to ask Mathematica to give me possible closed forms from a given numerical approximation

Tags: algorithm, approximation

Imagine I am solving a some Infinite Series and I cannot directly compute the value using Mathematica.

The value of this series approximates $ 0.785398....$ (Actually is $\frac{\pi}{4}$). I want to be able to feed this decimal to Mathematica and ask it so give me possible numbers in the realm of $A\pi$ where A is some constant ( I specify to the program that the solution might be in $A\pi$ form) .

How to do this? If there exists any source of information on this please do direct me to it.

For Example: In this  ---> https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/0910.2684/ paper the authors use an algorithm in maple to find an approximation to Apery's Constant given some possible solution.

Condensed --> Give mathematica a number and ask it to find me possible constants (in a form that I believe will be the answer) that match the number I give it.

Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: `Rationalize[0.785398/Pi, 10^-6]` finds $A$ from the given information. I don't think the functionality exists for a general search without such strong hypotheses about the form of the answer.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like the [AskConstants](https://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) package?

Comment: @ydd that is a really nice package indeed